# Multiple modal views prevents background from dimming/disabling with UIModalPresentationPageSheet

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

So when you present a modal view with UIModalPresentationPageSheet presentation style on iPad, the view behind the modal view will get dimmed and will be disabled.  However, if you have a modal view present on top of another (full page) modal view, it seems that the dimming/disabling does not happen.  Anyone know of a way around this?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this all depends which controller is being used to present the modal view controller. I've found that when using `UISplitViewController`, presenting a modal view controller from anything the but the split view controller itself doesn't apply the dimming. I'd be interested to see more code replicating what you're describing.

Comment: In my case, i have the modal window presenting a second modal window.  I have a feeling that this prevents it from dimming.